# How to do Java based open social applications development

Tags: java, opensocial

Please suggest where can I find good resources (tutorial/books/example code etc) for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [opensocial-development-environment](https://sites.google.com/site/opensocialdevenv/user-guide) is very useful for developing OS applications. You can test your applications locally and generate Java RESTful client stubs easily.

Answer (score 1):

couple of links:

http://wiki.opensocial.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

http://code.google.com/apis/opensocial/

http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-java-client/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opensocial